# Retrieve multiple items in Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following data structure in Firestore:

```
{
  items: [
    itemId1: {},
    itemId2: {},
    itemId3: {}
  ],
  users: [
    userId1: {
      itemIds: [
        "itemId1",
        "itemId3"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The goal of this data structure is for many users to have access to and collaborate on the same items. So moving the items into each user would be rather inefficient and difficult.

If I have the userId (`userId1`), I would like to query the items collection for all items that are within the user's `itemIds` array.

So, in this example, it would return `[itemId1: {}, itemId3: {}]`.

My application is one using Angular (`7.2.1`) and Angularfire.

If my data structures are inherently flawed, let me know and I can attempt to change them.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: The way you have it now, you can't do this in one query.  In fact, you will need to do one get() for the user and its list of items, then another get() for each item found in the list.  (In other words, there is no "SQL join" like feature in Firestore.)

Comment: Are there any recommended data design patterns for a collaborative application such as this?

Comment: I think it depends on how you want the UI to operate. I do some of this when I have a shared pool of things, but only one thing can be edited by a user at a time. For example, if a team has 5 users and 3 games scheduled, I have all 5 users denormalized onto the team, as well as the 3 games. When I denormalize, I decide what fields matter. So for the users, it's their name, id, and maybe their number and position. For the games, it's date/time, opponent name, simple location, id. You have up to 1MB of data in a document before it becomes inefficient in Firestore, but careful with no save limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.afs.doc('users/' + userId1).valueChanges().subscribe(itemIds=>{
  itemIds.forEach(itemId=>{
    this.afs.doc<Item>('items/'+ itemId).valueChanges().subscribe(item=> {
      console.log(item);
    });
  })
});
```

you can try this one.
the first *afs.doc* retrieves the itemId array from *users* collection 
the *forEach* traverses through all the *itemIds* and make another firestore query to *items* collection with document id as _itemId

> I havent run the code. but it should clear the idea of how to query such structures. Hope that answers your question